# Android - Use String from 2nd Activities for List on 1st activity

Tags: java, android, list, android-activity

I currently started working on Android and right now i am trying to figure out how to send an Intent From a 2nd Activity to the first!

Now i know that i have to use startActivityForResult and i think i actually used that the right way.
However there is a list on my Main Activity, that i want to fill with a String from my 2nd Activity. But i cant get the List to update without getting a NullPointer Exception when trying to add the received String to the List.

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

I think my issues lay in some Activity Order issues. How do i send the receivedString from OnActivityResult to OnResume once the 2nd activity is finished().
Or The Actualy String coming over from my 2nd activity is always empty for some reason, but i cant figure out why that would be the case...

ANSWER FOUND CHECK POST Beneath

Comment: Check if the meeting name is not null.
    MeetingName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
if(MeetingName==null)Log.e("NULL","MeetingNameView is NULL");

Comment: The exception says that you are doing operation with null object.Try checking values especially `MeetingName` from creation to `onActivityResult`

Comment: vinitus solved the problem but thank you all very much!!! I simply didnt use the right Intent.... but everything else is fine :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're not getting the right intent in the result. Change:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     //check for right result
     if (requestCode == 10) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Catching name from 2nd Activity
            Intent GoToMain = getIntent();
```

To:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//check for right result
if (requestCode == 10) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //Catching name from 2nd Activity
            Intent GoToMain = data;
```

Comment: Oh my God i spend the the last 3 hours trying to figure this out and i was too oblivious to see that. You are my hero of the Day!!!!!!!!!!!!!